# Count repeat of a specific value in a column in every 365 rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have daily observations from 31 years of data and each year has 365 days, so my dataset contains 11,315 rows.

Each row only has four values including 5, 7, 8 and 9.

How can I use (groupby) to count the repeats of 5, 7, 8 and 9 every 365 row??

Comment: can you give an example dataframe with an expected result ?

Comment: You ignore leap days?

Answer (score 2):

You can group a block of consecutive number of rows like this:

```
your_series.groupby(np.arange(len(your_series))//365).value_counts()
```

You would get a doubly-indexed series like:

```
0  5   3
   7   100
   8   200
   9   52
1  5   
...
```

You can also use `crosstab`:

```
pd.crosstab(np.arange(len(your_series))//365, your_series)
```

and you would get a dataframe similar to:

```
    5    7    8    9
0   3  100  200   52
1   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, when I run it give me error of:
'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'value_counts'

when I use the column in array format:
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'groupby'
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'crosstab'

Comment: That’s because your data is a numpy array. `your_series` is a pandas series, as in `your_series = pd.Series(your_numpy_array)`. The crosstab route should still work, remember it’s `pd.crosstab`.